# Arduino: includes between libraries

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm trying to include [IRLIB2](https://github.com/cyborg5/IRLib2) into my sketch. As a sandbox, I'm using this code (which compiles fine without the include):

```
#include <IRLibAll.h>

void setup(){}
void loop(){}
```

IRLib2 is packaged into a set of individual libraries. There are five of them, all have to be installed separately via the arduino library manager. I've followed the instructions on the repository regarding this. My sketchbook folder now looks like this:
[image: libraries]

This layout causes problems for me. The include statement generates the following error message:

```
/home/lhk/sketchbook/libraries/IRLib2/IRLibAll.h:22:0,
                 from sketch_mar04f.ino:1:
/home/lhk/sketchbook/libraries/IRLib2/IRLibDecodeBase.h:13:28: fatal error: IRLibProtocols.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The missing IRLibProtocols.h is located in the IRLibProtocols library.

This seems like a common problem: Libraries using each other. In CMake, I could set up the include directories appropriately, but here the only tool I can see is that "Add Library" dialogue from the arduino IDE.

The IRLibAll.h is supposed to bring include everything from IRLib2. It is also possible to import the libraries individually, but that doesn't solve the problem of include paths.
How can I set up my code to properly to include libraries that reference each other ?

I have also created an [issue](https://github.com/cyborg5/IRLib2/issues/49) on the repository:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino IDE versions 1.6.5-r5 and older often require you to add `#include` directives to your sketch for library dependencies in order for the Arduino IDE to know which folders need to be added to the include path.

**So one solution would be to add the following lines to your sketch:**

```cpp
#include <IRLibProtocols.h>
#include <IRLibRecv.h>
#include <IRLibRecvPCI.h>
#include <IRLibFreq.h>
```

An improved system of dependency scanning was added with the [arduino-builder](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder) tool in Arduino IDE 1.6.6. Using any recent version of the Arduino IDE your sketch will compile without adding any additional `#include` directives.

**Thus, the better solution is to update to the latest official version of the Arduino IDE.**

Due to [license documentation issues[(https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/2703), when you install the Arduino IDE via `apt install arduino`, etc. you get a very outdated version, which is a somewhat modified equivalent of 1.0.5. You miss out on all the improvements that have been made in the last 4 years. It's best to always install the official Arduino IDE downloaded from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software.

Comment: Oh sorry, my Screenshot is confusing. The path shown on top includes an IRLib2 folder, because that is the history of visited folders. My current folder is libraries, it is shown more black. Libraries contains the other folders directly.

Comment: It works fine for me with Arduino IDE 1.8.5 on Raspbian. Check to be sure that the file /home/lhk/sketchbook/libraries/IRLibProtocols/IRLibProtocols.h exists.

Comment: the problem was my IDE version. It labelled itself as 2:1.0.5, and I thought it was a version 2.x, actually it's a very outdated 1.0.5. The package sources seem rather out-of-date.
Now it compiles fine.
Thanks